# Unable to execute "Commit" in ADODB.COMMAND

Tags: excel, vba, oracle11g, adodb

I am running Excel VBA code which is connecting to an Oracle DB and ADODB. 
I am able to connect to Oracle server using following Connection String:
`dbConnectStr = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST='Host')(PORT='Port'))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME='service')));Data Source='Source'; User Id='User';Password='Password"`

```
With dbConnection
    .ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
    .Properties("Prompt") = adPromptNever
    .Open ConnectionString
End With
```

I am able to execute Select Commands.

But when I try to execute following SQL Update command which is followed by a "COMMIT", I get Oracle error : ORA-0091: invalid character.

On omitting Commit, the error disappears.

```
   sSQL = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET DOJ ='31-DEC-9999' WHERE EMP_ID =55555; COMMIT;"

    With dbCommand
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
        .CommandText = sSQL
        .CommandType = adCmdUnknown
        .CommandTimeout = 600
    End With

    Set dbRecordset = dbCommand.Execute
```

Having "COMMIT" in the SQL is my integral requirement, which I can not ignore or replace with something else.

Please help. Thanks in advance
Sachin D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update and the commit are 2 commands. You cannot execute both command in the same execute. You will need to do 2 executes. Usually you should split your script with something like `Split(sSQL, ";")`. This will give you an array of strings which can be traversed easily with a for loop.

You must also be in transaction mode for the commit to be accepted in a command execute. You can do this by surrounding your loop with `dbConnection.BeginTrans` and `dbConnection.CommitTrans`.

If you are not in transaction mode, each execute will commit immediately.

Comment: Without a transaction, commit is executed by default?

Answer (score -2):

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer * requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSString *ua = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";

    [requestSerializer setValue:ua forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/xml", nil];
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

    NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://unicodesystems.co.in:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=abc&username=%@&password=%@&groups=unicode",chatNameText.text,passText.text];
    NSLog(@"url %@",url);
    [manager POST:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
       parameters:nil
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

              NSData * data = (NSData *)responseObject;
              NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:[NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
              NSLog(@"xml %@",xmlDoc);
//              DBManager * db = [[DBManager alloc] init];
              [DBManager getSharedInstance];
              NSLog(@"AGE:%@  %@    %@    %@",aText.text,chatNameText.text,gText.text,passText.text);
//              NSArray *fields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"chat_name", @"age", @"gender", @"password", nil];
//              NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:chatNameText.text,aText.text,gText.text,passText.text, nil];
//              
//              [db saveData:fields value:values table:@"Login_user_data"];
              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"login" forKey:@"initial_step"];
              loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
              [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just dumping a block of code here does not help anyone. Can you please clarify what this code does and why it solves the problem?